# Vue : How to implement Table search

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, vue.js

I have a simple search functionality on table. 
But somehow its not working,

**I should be be getting filtered rows on the table while searching**.

Following is the code:

```
// Search Input
 <div class="dv-header-search">
    <input type="text" class="dv-header-input"
      placeholder="Search"
      v-model="query.search_input">
  </div>

//Table row
<tr v-for="row in filteredRow">
    <td v-for="(value, key) in row">{{value}}</td>
</tr>

data() {
  return {
    model: { data: [] },
    columns: {},
    query: {
      search_input: ''
    },
  }
},

// Setting model after API call
.then(function(response) {
    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
})

computed: {
  filteredRow: function(){
    return this.model.data.filter((row) => {
      return row;
    });
  }
}
```

Now the `filteredRow` calls on `page load`, What am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

````
```
  filteredRow: function(){
    return this.model.data.filter((row) => {
      return row;
    });
  }
```

should be 

```
  filteredRow: function(){
    return this.model.data.filter((row) => {
      // containOrNot should return bool
      return containOrNot(row, this.query.search_input)
    });
  }
```
````

Comment: `ContainOrNot` will be function defined in methods right ?

Comment: Yes. Something like ```containOrNot (row, search_input) { 
 if (row.indexOf(search_string) !== -1) { return false } else {return true }} ```

Comment: `rowindexOf` is undefined.

Comment: sorry ```row.indexof()```

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredRow: function(){
    return this.model.data.filter((row) => {
     //i don't know you value key.. so just picking first property
     for(var key in row){
        return String(row[key]).indexOf(this.query.search_input);
       }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks sunil, It make more sense. I am getting `row[key].indexOf is not a function`.

Comment: then what is the type of value which is coming at row[key]?

Comment: they are string and numbers, I `console.log(typeof row[key]);` and its giving me strings and numbers.
`

Comment: `this.model.data` an array having objects with key value pair.

Comment: I have change the code to convert to string and search.. Hope it works for you